# dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.

Tags: dpkg

```
murphy@murphy-Compaq-Presario-C700-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo apt-get install clipgrab
[sudo] password for murphy: 
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem. 
murphy@murphy-Compaq-Presario-C700-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo dpkg
dpkg: error: need an action option

Type dpkg --help for help about installing and deinstalling packages [*];
Use `dselect' or `aptitude' for user-friendly package management;
Type dpkg -Dhelp for a list of dpkg debug flag values;
Type dpkg --force-help for a list of forcing options;
Type dpkg-deb --help for help about manipulating *.deb files;

Options marked [*] produce a lot of output - pipe it through `less' or `more' !
murphy@murphy-Compaq-Presario-C700-Notebook-PC:~$
```

am getting this error when i try to install clipgrab. please help

Comment: It didnt work for me. Any other suggestion?